# JSF not retaining the original List and mixing modified and original List OR How to do a deep copy of an ArrayList in JSF 2.0 ModelBean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF2.0 in my application.
The business requirement in my project is such that when page loads a list is displayed. The list is coming from DAO layer or web service layer. Lets call this original List.
Now we have 2 lists, copies of each other in which is just the original list and the other is bounded to the JSF

Now the list is editable list so I am using a  to display the list and each cell in the  is a .
Now on click of SAVE button the modified list by the user (since the list is editable) is compared with the original list. 
Only if the 2 lists are different then the modified list is sent back to webservice.
The problem and issue that I am facing is that in the first line of save() method itself both the original and modified list is exactly same and point only to the modified list.
So I am unable to compare the 2 lists.

My implementation is as below-

PhaseListener is calling below method on page load

```
 public String populateDataTable() {

        this.orderList = new ArrayList<ItemOrder>();
        this.originalOrderList = new ArrayList<ItemOrder>();
        MockWebService mockService = new MockWebService();
        this.setOrderList(mockService.mockWSMethod());
        this.originalOrderList = this.getOrderList();//i know this is where i am doing something wrong. i need to deep copy a list. but for this i cannot make an additional web service call and call that web service again and store the list in originalOrderList
        return "view";
    }
```

On click of save button

```
    public String saveAction() {
        boolean isSame = true; // true if same and false if different
        for (int i = 0; i < this.originalOrderList.size(); i++) {
            if (!this.originalOrderList.get(i).equals(this.orderList.get(i))) {
                isSame = false;
            }
        }
//however both originalOrderList and orderList have the same modified List.
        if (isSame == true) {
            System.out.println("Same lists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Different lists");
        }
        return "default";
    }
```

Please do help me.

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the problem you are facing is `originalOrderList` is a shallow copy of `orderList` (assuming getOrderList() is returning an `orderList` reference). In your case both orderList and originalOrderList are references pointing to the same ArrayList object and if a change is made to the value of your `orderList`, then the `originalOrderList` reflects that change because it shares the same reference.

The solution is to do a deep copy of your `originalOrderList` :

```
this.originalOrderList = this.getOrderList().clone();
```

if your `ItemOrder` is an immutable object otherwise :

```
public static List<ItemOrder> cloneList(List<ItemOrder> list) {
    List<ItemOrder> clone = new ArrayList<ItemOrder>(list.size());
    for(ItemOrderitem: list) clone.add(item.clone());
    return clone;
}
```

and you will have to get your ItemOrder object to implement the Cloneable interface, and implement the clone() method.